# how to access custom header value in log_format nginx

Tags: php, nginx, server

I have added a custom header which comes in all response headers.

header details: `X-name`

I wanted to log the above custom header value in nginx access log using log_format. I have tried with **$sent_http_x_name**, **$upstream_http_x_name** and **$http_x_name**, but nothing is working.

Same time I am able to log a system header "**X-Powered-By**" by using **$upstream_http_x_powered_by**

I am using `nginx 1.4.1` in `Linux`

Is there any nginx version dependency with `$upstream_http module`?

please help... thanks in advance...

Comment: It should work. What is your nginx config?

Comment: It is working...

Comment: Post the solution to get it to work. @SreejithPm